# How to import data in a text file as a 3d matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a text file with the values stored as a single column. I need to import the data into matlab as a 3d matrix. How to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Import them as a 1D matrix and then use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

[`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) might help you with the import

and if your data is row-major, then you will want to use `permute` at the end.